# How to edit axis titles of a faceted-ggplot-object converted to a plotly-object using the function ggplotly()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, axis-labels

I recently remarked that `plotly::ggplotly()`, when used on a faceted-ggplot-object, creates axis titles as annotations *i.e.* they can not be changed using `layout(yaxis = ...)` as proposed [here](https://plotly.com/r/figure-labels/).

What is the intended way of editing axis labels of a faceted-ggplot-object?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)
ex <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Petal.Width)) +
  facet_grid(.~ Species)
# Fails
plotly::ggplotly(ex) %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(title = list(text = "My title")))
```

[image]

```r
# Possible workaround
ex1 <- plotly::ggplotly(ex)
ex1$x$layout$annotations[[2]]$text <- "My title"
ex1
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I don't think there is an intended manner to change it. If you wanted to be able to control the titles in the Plotly style (not as annotations as you discovered in through `ggplotly`), you can assign the new label with layout and delete the annotation.